# How to reference a linq collection, inside of the same linq chain?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I reference a list created earlier by linq, in that very same linq chain?

Here:

```
var prices = new List<decimal>(){5.96m, 8, 1.5m, 3.4m, 8, 9, 3};
var multiPrices = prices.Select(p => Math.Round(p)).Where(p => **RoundedCollection**.Count(n => n == p) > 1)....
```

I need the **RoundedCollection** to be a reference to the rounded list created by the `prices.Select(p => Math.Round(p))` so that in the end, the `multiPrices` variable will contain rounded entries from the original collection which, after rounding, exist in the collection more than once.

This will be the contents of the final collection:

```
8, 3, 8, 3
```

Can this be done, without splitting the linq into two lines?

Thank you

Comment: @GrantWinney https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Comment: Just select a new anonymous type with all your data...

Comment: you basically are just rounding and looking for the values that are not unique.

Comment: Why don't you want to do this in 2 lines, differed execution will cause this to happen in 1 line essentially, and its easier to read.

Comment: Just a more readable one: `var fxn = prices.Select(p => Math.Round(p));
            var multiPrices = fxn.Where(p => fxn.Count(n => n == p) > 1);`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This will produce the desired output.

```
var prices = new List<decimal>() { 5.96m, 8, 1.5m, 3.4m, 8, 9, 3 };
var output = prices.Select(p => Math.Round(p)).Where(prices.Select(p => Math.Round(p))
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
        .Select(x => x.Key).Contains);
```

> 8,3,8,3

[.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nSd5c5)

Comment: Why do you need the join?

Comment: Why should one use this if `var fxn = prices.Select(p => Math.Round(p));
            var multiPrices = fxn.Where(p => fxn.Count(n => n == p) > 1);` is easier to read

Comment: Question is: `Can this be done, without splitting the linq into two lines?`

Comment: @L.B - It is / I did. See the last lambda statement. I think you beat me on the down-vote by 10 seconds while I was adding it.

Comment: @Igor And you propose this as a solution just because OP wants a one-liner.  Not faster, not shorter. Compare it with my two-liner(same as OP's code)

Comment: @L.B - What am I going to add to my solution that has not already been stated in the comments? I do not want to copy/paste anything that others, you included, have already pointed out. As you already commented above, they want it with 1 line and that is what I provided even though it might not be the cleanest or fastest solution.